# Check if part of text is in tuple

Tags: python, tuples

How to check if part of text is in tuple?
For example:

```
my_data = ((1234L,), (23456L,), (3333L,))
```

And we need to find if 123 or 1234 is in tuple.
I didn't worked lot with tuples before.
In array we use:

```
if variable in array
```

But its not working for tuples like `my_data`

PS. 1st answer solved problem.

Comment: Is it _text_ or _numbers_ you need to search (your example contains numbers); and do you want to find an exact match, or just if any element _contains_ the key. So in your case your are searching for `123`, but there is `1234`; should this be a match (because it starts with `123`) or no match (because it isn't exactly `123`)?

Comment: @Emin you can find your answer here.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917372/how-to-search-a-list-of-tuples-in-python

Comment: @Surinderツ Name of that topic is How to search a list of tuples in Python and of course i know how to search it, so, that's why i couldn't find that post in search.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i wrote how to check if PART of text is in tuple, so, i don't need exact mach of text.

Comment: @EminMastizada The Link I have provided is not the direct answer to the questions you asked. Its just a reference to get the idea on how to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Surinderツ thanks :) But you wrote it after somebody answered to the question, and users of stackoverflow are doing that when the question is copy of already answered question. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def findIt(data, num):
    num = str(num)
    return any(num in str(i) for item in data for i in item)

data = ((1234L,), (23456L,), (3333L,))
print findIt(data, 123)
```

**Output**

```
True
```