# Search a list of tuples and return multiple results

Tags: python, list, search, tuples

I have a list of tuples each with 5 pieces of information in it. I need a way to search the list for a result or range of results from a search parameter or parameters.
So I'd like to search for an ID number (string) or name (string - only the whole name) or a range of salary so between (int - 10000-20000).
I read on another post [How to search a list of tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917372/how-to-search-a-list-of-tuples-in-python) that you can use list comprehensions

```
t = [[0] for x in l].index('12346')
```

but it wasn't explained all that well and it doesn't satisfy the range of values I need to enter.
This does it's job for one entry. But if 2 people have the same first name or job it will just display the first occurrence. To display the correct tuple I take the value T and send it to the my printing function to display. Which again won't work for multiple entries because I would need to know how many tuples were returned beforehand.

Here are a few tuples, all are very similar.

```
('12349', '30000', 'Wizard', 'Harry', 'Potter')
('12350', '15000', 'Entertainer', 'Herschel Shmoikel', 'Krustofski')
('13123', '75000', 'Consultant', 'David', 'Beckham')
('13124', '150000', 'Manager', 'Alex', 'Ferguson')
('13125', '75000', 'Manager', 'Manuel', 'Pellegrini')
```

Thank you

Comment: Post some more code, maybe some of your list of tuples.

Answer (score 1):

```
t = [x for x in l if x[0] == '12346']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [e for e in l if int(e[1]) > 10000 and int(e[1]) < 20000]
[('12350', '15000', 'Entertainer', 'Herschel Shmoikel', 'Krustofski')]
```

Comment: If I add 12347 20000 Secretary Lisa Simpson
12348 20000 Secretary Hermione Grainger how would I do this to return all 3 of the results between 10000 >= int(e[1]) =<20000

Comment: `[e for e in l if int(e[1]) >= 10000 and int(e[1]) <= 20000]`