# How to know if a branch is closed using its changeset?

Tags: python, mercurial, hglib

An in-house build system builds every commit made on a branch. But, in Mercurial, to close a branch you have to make "close commit" kinda thing, triggering a build for that commit.

This is a problem because we are wasting resources on unnecessary builds.

We are using *hglib* to do all the mercurial code.

```
(changeset.branch(), changeset.rev(), str(changeset)) in self.repo.Branches()
```

I tried this command, but this will ignore the previous commits because I know it's only checking if it exists as a branch in repo.

Is there any way to know, via changeset or another thing, if a commit on a branch is a 'close commit'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, this is what I was looking for:

```
self.Client.log(revrange="closed()")
```

This will return:

```
[(revision, changeset, tag, branch name, 'username', description, date)]
```

This is just a tuple, so for that:

[How to search a list of tuples in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917372/how-to-search-a-list-of-tuples-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

The `close` information is stored in the changeset extras. I'm not sure how to access it through hglib but you can access it through a templated log call: `hg log -r 2 -T "{extras|json}\n"`:

`{"branch": "branch", "close": "1", "topic": "laconic-kouprey"}`